# When you have a function with a string parameter, does that create another instance of the string?

Tags: c#

When you have a function with a string parameter, does that create another instance of the string when the function is called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's a reference to the same immutable instance.  This means that if you assign it a new value within the method, all you've done is change the local reference to point to a different, equally immutable string.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are reference types, albeit immutable reference types.

By default, parameters are passed by value, which for a reference type variable is the reference. Since the String class is immutable however, any changes to a string passed to a method will change the local reference to point to a new immutable string instance, as Steven has already stated.

You may find [Jon Skeet's article on parameter passing](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) enlightening

Comment: Good link.  Surprised Jon isn't here himself to share it.